# Perl: Decode Timestamp in a Binary File

Tags: perl, datetime, decode, binaryfiles

I have a fixed-width binary file that I'm decoding. One of the fields is the time stamp. It is 5 bytes long, and of the format `SS SS SS SS MS`. The first four bytes represents seconds from the data 2000/01/01 00:00:00 and the `MS` byte provides greater accuracy by representing the number of 10ms interval multiples within the second (value range is 0 to 99).

The Encoding type of this field is Binary. Eg: The answer time is `2008-4-28 14:42:51.15`, the field is filled with `0F A8 9E EB 0F`.

How do I parse and convert the binary data into the timestamp format in Perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) module is suitable for this purpose, and it has been a core module since version 10 of Perl 5 so it shouldn't need installing.

Also, [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) is the most convenient way to extract the data fields from the string.

It would look like this. I have used `pack` to create the file contents that you describe, and I had to append the fractional seconds to the result separately as `Time::Piece` doesn't support parts of a second.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $data = pack 'H*', '0FA89EEB0F';

print decode_timestamp($data), "\n";

sub decode_timestamp {
   my ($seconds, $ms) = unpack 'N C', shift;
   my $base = Time::Piece->strptime('2000-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d');
   ($base + $seconds)->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') . sprintf '.%02d', $ms;
}
```

**output**

```
2008-04-28 14:42:51.15
```

Comment: Thanks ! Esp. bcoz of the use of a core module.

Answer (score 4):

use the [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment) CPAN module:

```
use Time::Moment;

my $data    = 0x0FA89EEB0F;
my $seconds = $data >> 8;     # Right shift to remove fractional second.
my $milliseconds = 10 * ( $data & 0xff );    # Hundredths to Milli

my $tm = Time::Moment->new( year => 2000, month => 1, day => 1 );  #base datetime
my $tm2 = $tm->plus_seconds($seconds)->plus_milliseconds($milliseconds);
print $tm2, "\n";    #<-- prints: 2008-04-28T14:42:51.150Z
```

Comment: Miguel Prz, `day => 21` should probably be `day => 1`.

Comment: You have one too few Fs in the mask. It should be `0xFFFFFFFF00` - you're lucky the top byte in the data is less than `0x10`! Also there's no need to mask the value at all before the right-shift: the unwanted byte just falls off the end, and you don't need to set it to zero first. The base date should be `1-Jan-2000`, not `21-Jan-2000`, so your result is twenty days late. And lastly, the bottom byte is in units of *10ms*, or 100ths of a second, so the fractional part should be `.15`, not `.015`.